How to find and obtain the SecretURL for disk_encryption_key block for resource "azurerm_managed_disk" in terraform
I'm struggling to find and obtain the secretURL used for the disk encryption key encryption block for the azurerm_managed_disk resource block in terraform.  Anyone know how to obtain this?  The docs states this, but not sure how to get the secret of the key in the key vault.

secret_url - (Required) The URL to the Key Vault Secret used as the
Disk Encryption Key. This can be found as id on the
azurerm_key_vault_secret resource.

 data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name = var.disk_encryption_key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.disk_encryption_key_rg
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_key" "encryption-kv" {
  name         = var.disk_encryption_key_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "data" {
      count                = var.data_disk_count
      name                 = "${var.vm_name}-DataDisk-${count.index + 1}"
      location             = var.location
      resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
      storage_account_type = var.data_disk_storage_account_type
      create_option        = "Empty"
      disk_size_gb         = var.data_disk_size_gb
      tags                 = var.tags
    
      encryption_settings {
        enabled = true
        disk_encryption_key {
          secret_url      = 
          source_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.key_vault_id
        }
        key_encryption_key {
          key_url         = "https://${data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.name}.vault.usgovcloudapi.net/keys/${var.disk_encryption_key_name}/${data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.version}"
          source_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.key_vault_id
        }
      }
    
    }


To obtain the secret_url for the disk_encryption_key, use the azurerm_key_vault_secret data source to fetch the secret associated with your encryption key @NickP refer:https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_secret


Setting up SecretURL for disk_encryption_key block for resource "azurerm_managed_disk" using terraform

The Blocker you mentioned is due to use of depreciating encryption_settings inside disk configuration.
In order to use the Secret URL for  disk_encryption_key block you need to use the azurerm_disk_encryption_set  to pass the encryption key from the vault & also the vault should have all necessary permissions.

I tried the terraform configuration with the necessary changes so that you can use the key and secret from the vault.
My terraform configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "disk_encryption_key_vault_name" {
  default = "samvksbbb"
}

variable "disk_encryption_key_rg" {
  default = "vkk-resources"
}

variable "disk_encryption_key_name" {
  default = "samplekey"
}

variable "disk_encryption_secret_name" {
  default = "samplesecret"
}

variable "data_disk_count" {
  default = 1
}

variable "vm_name" {
  default = "samplevmvk"
}

variable "location" {
  default = "westus2"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  default = "vkk-resources"
}

variable "data_disk_storage_account_type" {
  default = "Standard_LRS"
}

variable "data_disk_size_gb" {
  default = 1024
}

variable "tags" {
  default = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}


data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = var.disk_encryption_key_vault_name
  resource_group_name = var.disk_encryption_key_rg
}


data "azurerm_key_vault_key" "encryption_kv_key" {
  name         = var.disk_encryption_key_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}


data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "encryption_secret" {
  name         = var.disk_encryption_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
      name                = "encryptionset"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      key_vault_key_id    = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption_kv_key.id
      encryption_type = "EncryptionAtRestWithCustomerKey"
    
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
}


# Resource block to create a Managed Disk with encryption settings
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "data" {
  count                = var.data_disk_count
  name                 = "${var.vm_name}-DataDiskq-${count.index + 1}"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  storage_account_type = var.data_disk_storage_account_type
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.data_disk_size_gb
  tags                 = var.tags
  disk_encryption_set_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.id

}

Deployment succeeded:



Make sure you add permission for managed identity created
in azurerm_disk_encryption_set  follow the SO
key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]

which will help you have better understanding on that permission & also Location of vault and disk should match.
Refer:
Azure portal - Enable customer-managed keys with SSE - managed disks - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn

I don't have azure account, so can't test it, but terraform is terraform, so it is going to be this:
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                       = "examplekeyvault"
  ...
}

Now you need to add azurerm_key_vault_secret resource:
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

And now you can pull the id of the azurerm_key_vault_secret resource.
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "data" {
  count                = var.data_disk_count
  name                 = "${var.vm_name}-DataDisk-${count.index + 1}"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  storage_account_type = var.data_disk_storage_account_type
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.data_disk_size_gb
  tags                 = var.tags

  encryption_settings {
    enabled = true
    disk_encryption_key {
      secret_url      = azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.id  <- this is it
      source_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.key_vault_id
    }
    key_encryption_key {
      key_url         = "https://${data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.name}.vault.usgovcloudapi.net/keys/${var.disk_encryption_key_name}/${data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.version}"
      source_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.encryption-kv.key_vault_id
    }
  }

}

